# What does the sentence mean about the recruiter and the developer?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Here's a paragraph gives some advice for programmers looking for a job:

> Avoid recruiters at this stage in your career. Sorry to say, but the good recruiters don’t care about novice programmers. Nor should they. Additionally, once you get hooked up with a recruiter, in order for someone to hire you, they have stroke a check to the recruiter. A novice programmer is a long term investment for a company – you’ll get more out of them than they get out of you for quite some time. **One junior developer looks a lot like every other junior developer in terms of potential – except the one with the recruiter costs more money that only the recruiter gets.**
>
> From [*A Guide for the Novice Programmer*](http://stablekernel.com/blog/the-stack-overflow-generation-a-guide-for-the-novice-programmer/) (long post)

What does the last bold font sentence mean about the developer?

It'd be great if someone could tell how to split this sentence for easy understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All junior developers are very similar in terms of potential.
2. Junior developers who work with recruiters cost more money to hire, because employers need to pay the recruiter.
3. Junior developers who work with recruiters don't even receive the extra money it costs to hire them.

Comment: thanks for quick and exact answer ! Does the last sentence mean that a junior developer looks similar with the others in potential but looks worse if he's hired by a recruiter?

Comment: No problem! It means that junior developers who are hired by recruiters are seen as being the same in potential, but more expensive.